# Hiding GroupBox Border

Tags: vb.net, grouping, panel

I am using Groups in VB .Net to group radio buttons together but I do not want the border around my groups to be displayed.  Is there anyway to hide this?  I have heard the suggestion of using a panel as opposed to a group but will this provide the grouping functionality needed for my radio buttons to perform properly??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a panel, but the user kind of needs to know which selections are mutually exclusive

Comment: So if I put to radio buttons in a panel, they will be grouped just as if I had put them into a group, and when the user selects the unselected button the previously selected one will be unselected?

Comment: yes, it is a container control just like the groupbox

Comment: just verified it, works perfect. Thanks!